# How to run a function with multiple arguments using pairs of columns with predefined list in R?

Tags: r, purrr

I have a long list of variables (a couple of hundreds) which stored as a file that I need to run a computation using `coalesce` to calculate the column with. Using the long list, if `var1` such as `x` is empty, I need to grab the value from `var2` which is `y`. The variable name stays the same as `var1` and the final table can get rid of `var2`.

Example of the `var_list` as below.

```
var_list <- tibble(
    var1 = c("x", "m"),
    var2 = c("y", "n"),
    new = c("x_new", "m_new")
)
```

The example data is:

```
data <- tibble(
    x = 1:10,
    y = 2:11,
   m = c(NA, 2, 4, 6, NA,
         7, 1, 9, NA, NA),
   n = c(NA, 4, 5, 6, 0,
         7, 1, 9, 0, NA)
)
```

```
The desired output is a tibble with 10 x 2:
x   y 
1   NA    
2   2  
3   4  
4   6  
5   0   
6   7   
7   1   
8   9   
9   0   
10  NA
```

I have tried this but it is not working as expected:

```
data %>% 
    mutate(with(var_list,
                set_names(coalesce(.[var1], .[var2]), var1)))
```

Any thought on this? Thanks

Comment: What is the point of the `var_list$new`?

Comment: @s_baldur sorry, I should have deleted it but since a lot of answers below are referring to that variable so I will just keep it here.

Answer (score 3):

For these type of operations, I like to use `glue`:

1. Create an `exprs` object with the operations to be applied to the set of columns.
2. Indicate their names.
3. Use `!!!rlang::parse_exprs` to execute the expressions

```r
library(glue)
library(dplyr)
exprs        <- glue("coalesce({var_list$var1}, {var_list$var2})")
names(exprs) <- var_list$new

data |> 
  transmute(!!!rlang::parse_exprs(exprs))

#    x_new m_new
#  1     1    NA
#  2     2     2
#  3     3     4
#  4     4     6
#  5     5     0
#  6     6     7
#  7     7     1
#  8     8     9
#  9     9     0
# 10    10    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `map2_dfc`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map2_dfc(var_list$var1, var_list$var2, ~coalesce(data[[.x]], data[[.y]])) %>%
  rlang::set_names(var_list$new) %>%
  bind_cols(data, .) %>% 
  select(all_of(var_list$new))
```

```
   x_new m_new
   <int> <dbl>
 1     1    NA
 2     2     2
 3     3     4
 4     4     6
 5     5     0
 6     6     7
 7     7     1
 8     8     9
 9     9     0
10    10    NA
```

Comment: If you use `pmap()` instead of `map2()` you can simplify things by including the new column names in the anonymous function - `pmap(var_list, \(var1, var2, new) tibble("{new}" := coalesce(data[[var1]], data[[var2]]))) |> bind_cols()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

foo <- \(x) do.call(coalesce, data[unlist(x)])
cols <- c("var1", "var2")


map(transpose(var_list[cols]), foo) |>
  setNames(var_list$new) |> 
  as_tibble()
 
#    x_new m_new
#    <int> <dbl>
#  1     1    NA
#  2     2     2
#  3     3     4
#  4     4     6
#  5     5     0
#  6     6     7
#  7     7     1
#  8     8     9
#  9     9     0
# 10    10    NA
```